# Does Terraform supports creating CloudFront RTMP-Distributions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, terraform

I know Terraform can create "normal" AWS CloudFront Distributions; but can it also create those with the RTMP Delivery Method?

Could not find any information in the Terraform docs...

And if yes, how to declare the delivery method as RTMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTMP distributions don't appear to be supported by Terraform.  [The docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html) do mention Microsoft Smooth Streaming but that's not what you want.

Radek Simko (Hashicorp) also mentions it [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/1780#issuecomment-98404489), but I could not find any further references within the documentation.

I think you're out of luck.